# Can't input accentuated characters in JPasswordField on Ubuntu

Tags: java, swing, ubuntu, jpasswordfield

In a swing application I have text fields and password fields. On Windows everything is fine. On Ubuntu (14-16) I can input accentuated characters in the `JTextField`, but not in the `JPasswordField`. At least not by typing (I can paste de accentuated char in the `JPasswordField`).

Here is an example code:

```
public class Frame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public Frame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jPasswordField1 = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.TRAILING);
        jLabel1.setText("textField");

        jLabel2.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.TRAILING);
        jLabel2.setText("passwordField");

        jPasswordField1.setEchoChar('\u0000');

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 95, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jPasswordField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 121, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1))
                .addContainerGap(79, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(28, 28, 28)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(jPasswordField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap(69, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Frame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JPasswordField jPasswordField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

The result on Windows:

[image]

The result on Ubuntu:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to link: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7052169.

I came across this issue, and fixed by setting :

`jPasswordField.enableInputMethod(true)`

Comment: It worked. I still don't know what are they saying with: _By default, JPasswordField disables input methods; otherwise, input characters could be visible while they were composed using input methods_